# How to put h3 to title of the faq area in accordion

Tags: html, css

I need to add the h3 to the title of the following code:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header"> <a class="collapsed card-link" data-toggle="collapse"  href="#collapseOne"> Title <span class="ti-angle-down"></span></a> </div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse"  data-parent="#accordion">
<div class="card-body"> section info </div>
</div>
</div>
```

the css is:

```
.card-header a{display:block;padding:24px 20px;text-decoration:none;font-size:18px;color:#4c5462;font-weight:500}
```

when I set the h3 to Title, the ti-angle-down go to the bottom of the div.

Any help to use the correct type?

Comment: what h3? Do you want to create a headline that is a link?

Comment: no, it is not necessary. Just put the title with h3.